# Select next item after removing selected item from sorted list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView, which filled by sorted data from CollectionViewSource, which filled from ObservableCollection. Like that

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsSortByName" Source="{Binding CountryData}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsSortByName}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStuff}"/>
```

How can I select next item in sorted list, when removing item from ObservableCollection. For example, we have following:

```
index id  name
0     1   1
1     3   3
2     4   4
```

Adding 2

```
index id  name
0     1   1
3     5   2 - SelectedStuff 
1     3   3
2     4   4
```

Remove 3 5 2 from ObservableCollection

```
CountryData.Remove(item);
```

How do I make 1 3 3 SelectedStuff?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SelectedIndex`. so try;

```
int i = ListView.SelectedIndex;
CountryData.Remove(item);
ListView.SelectedIndex = i;
```

Comment: But SelectedIndex will be 3. With all error checking and all SelectedStuff wil be the last item.

Comment: Then don't increment i. See my update and let me know if it works :)